# Performance Tuning an Existing Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

I'm a newbie to Oracle and have been given a task of improving some existing SQL queries currently running in a web based application. I've extracted the following query and ran it in SQL Developer to view the Explain information. I'm not very familiar with the Plan Table Output and looking for some help with possible improvements in the queries performance which takes about 2 seconds to return 50 rows.

Query:

```
SELECT PATD.StageName                                                                                     AS StageName,
  100 * (LINKS.NEVENTS - LINKS.NCONTACTS) / (DECODE(LINKS.NEVENTS,0,1,LINKS.NEVENTS))                     AS PERCENTREPEAT, 
  LINKS.NEVENTS                                                                                           AS NEVENTS,
  LINKS.NCONTACTS                                                                                         AS NCONTACTS,
  'STAGE'                                                                                                 AS DETAILLEVEL,
  LATD.LinkClassName                                                                                      AS LINKTYPE,
  PATD.ActivityGroupTxt                                                                                   AS PACTIVITYGROUP,
  SATD.ActivityGroupTxt                                                                                   AS SACTIVITYGROUP
FROM
  (SELECT NEVENTS ,
    NCONTACTS ,
    LINKTYPEKEY ,
    PACTIVITYGROUP ,
    SACTIVITYGROUP
  FROM
    (SELECT SUM (
      CASE
        WHEN CALF.PredActivityKey = -1
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
      END)                                AS NEVENTS,
      COUNT (DISTINCT CALF.RELATEDID)     AS NCONTACTS,
      CALF.predecessorlinkclasskey        AS LINKTYPEKEY,
      CALF.PredActivityKey                AS PACTIVITYGROUP,
      CALF.SuccActivityKey                AS SACTIVITYGROUP
    FROM
      (SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE GKEY = 4
      ) CALF
    JOIN TABLE_B DDate
    ON (DDate.DateKey=CALF.SegmentStartACDDateKey)
    WHERE CALF.segmentstartacddate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012-09-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2013-09-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND DDate.fullDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012-09-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2013-09-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    GROUP BY  CALF.predecessorlinkclasskey,
              CALF.PredActivityKey,
              CALF.SuccActivityKey
    ORDER BY NEVENTS DESC
    )
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 50
  ) LINKS
JOIN TABLE_C LATD
ON (LATD.linkclasskey=LINKS.LINKTYPEKEY)
JOIN TABLE_D PATD
ON (PATD.cfactivitykey=LINKS.PACTIVITYGROUP)
JOIN TABLE_D SATD
ON (SATD.cfactivitykey=LINKS.SACTIVITYGROUP)
```

Plan Table Ouput:

```
| Id  | Operation                               | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |                                                                                                                                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                  
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                         |    50 |  4550 |       | 54882   (1)| 00:10:59 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                              |                         |    50 |  4550 |       | 54882   (1)| 00:10:59 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                             |                         |    50 |  3850 |       | 54855   (1)| 00:10:59 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|   3 |    MERGE JOIN                           |                         |    50 |  2550 |       | 54829   (1)| 00:10:58 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | TABLE_C                 |     3 |    39 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|   5 |      INDEX FULL SCAN                    | PK_TABLE_C              |     3 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|*  6 |     SORT JOIN                           |                         |    50 |  1900 |       | 54827   (1)| 00:10:58 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|   7 |      VIEW                               |                         |    50 |  1900 |       | 54826   (1)| 00:10:58 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|*  8 |       COUNT STOPKEY                     |                         |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|   9 |        VIEW                             |                         |  1244K|    45M|       | 54826   (1)| 00:10:58 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|* 10 |         SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY           |                         |  1244K|    45M|    61M| 54826   (1)| 00:10:58 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  11 |          HASH GROUP BY                  |                         |  1244K|    45M|    61M| 54826   (1)| 00:10:58 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  12 |           VIEW                          | VW_DAG_0                |  1244K|    45M|       | 30184   (2)| 00:06:03 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  13 |            HASH GROUP BY                |                         |  1244K|    56M|    81M| 30184   (2)| 00:06:03 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|* 14 |             HASH JOIN                   |                         |  1244K|    56M|       | 15278   (2)| 00:03:04 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  15 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_B                 |   367 |  5138 |       |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|* 16 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN          | AKI_TABLE_B             |   367 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  17 |              PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR   |                         |  1247K|    40M|       | 15253   (2)| 00:03:04 |    40 |    92 |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  18 |               PARTITION HASH ALL        |                         |  1247K|    40M|       | 15253   (2)| 00:03:04 |     1 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                  
|* 19 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL        | TABLE_A                 |  1247K|    40M|       | 15253   (2)| 00:03:04 |   118 |   276 |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  20 |    PARTITION LIST ALL                   |                         | 10183 |   258K|       |    26   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  21 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | TABLE_D                 | 10183 |   258K|       |    26   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  22 |   PARTITION LIST ALL                    |                         | 10183 |   139K|       |    26   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  23 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | TABLE_D                 | 10183 |   139K|       |    26   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                  

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   1 - access("SATD"."cfactivitykey"="LINKS"."SACTIVITYGROUP")                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   2 - access("PATD"."cfactivitykey"="LINKS"."PACTIVITYGROUP")                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   6 - access("LATD"."LINKCLASSKEY"="LINKS"."LINKTYPEKEY")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
       filter("LATD"."LINKCLASSKEY"="LINKS"."LINKTYPEKEY")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   8 - filter(ROWNUM<=50)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  10 - filter(ROWNUM<=50)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  14 - access("DDATE"."DATEKEY"="TABLE_A"."SEGMENTSTARTACDDATEKEY")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  16 - access("DDATE"."FULLDATE">=TO_DATE(' 2012-09-25 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "DDATE"."FULLDATE"<=TO_DATE('                                                                                                                                                                                
              2013-09-25 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  19 - filter("GKEY"=4 AND "TABLE_A"."SEGMENTSTARTACDDATE">=TO_DATE(' 2012-09-25 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')                                                                                                                                                                            
              AND "TABLE_A"."SEGMENTSTARTACDDATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-09-25 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))                                                                                                                                                                                        

Note                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
-----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   - automatic DOP: skipped because of IO calibrate statistics are missing                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

 49 rows selected
```

Comment: Can you put in the table structures as well?

Why is there between when from and to dates are same?

Comment: Well you have some full table scans that *may* be a problem.  How many rows are in those tables?

Comment: The queries selecting a one year's worth of data. Unfortunately i don't have the DDL to hand.

Comment: Table_A has approx 2,500,000 rows, TABLE_B has approx 50,000 rows, TABLE_C has 25,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be classic performance issue arising out of 'pagination'. But, i tempted to look into this as SQL and execution plan were provided here.
If you search for large window like 12 months or so (*`BETWEEN '2012-09-25' AND '2013-09-25'`*), CBO is going follow and rely on FTS on all key tables. 
But, That may not that bad if proper partitions are in place. SQL can returns pretty fast (if not in desired 2 sec).

You most costly operations of your SQL is No 10 & 13 of plan output (SORT ORDER and GROUP BY ).

```
|* 10 |         SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY           |                         |  1244K|    45M|    61M| 54826   (1)| 00:10:58 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  11 |          HASH GROUP BY                  |                         |  1244K|    45M|    61M| 54826   (1)| 00:10:58 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  12 |           VIEW                          | VW_DAG_0                |  1244K|    45M|       | 30184   (2)| 00:06:03 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                  
|  13 |            HASH GROUP BY                |                         |  1244K|    56M|    81M| 30184   (2)| 00:06:03 |       |       |
```

Therefore, i would recommend the following (based on explain plan and assuming STATS are updated) :

1) **Global Index** on 'TABLE_A' to support costly '..GROUP BY':-

```
  CALF.predecessorlinkclasskey,
  CALF.PredActivityKey,
  CALF.SuccActivityKey
```

2) **Re-visit Partitions**: re-organize partitions (may be sub-partitions as well) on table (at least largest TABLE_A) to include the following:

Table_A:
partition on "GKEY" 
sub-partition on "SEGMENTSTARTACDDATE"

3) **Reduce the date range window**: I would also suggest you re-think and reduce the date range window to a more realistic and optimal level (may be a month or a Qtr)
There is no point traversing 1247K rows for 50 rows in hand.

4) Use GTT to park the interim output (You can experiment with it as a last resort. But, this will demand code re-factoring/ SQL splitting etc)

You may try all OR some of these options. **Make sure your stats (table/index) are up-to-update**.